# javascript functions with asynchronus ajax calls

Tags: javascript

I have 3 function calls in a method where all of them have a asynchronus ajax call in them. All these three functions returns a bool always true.

So in my code i have:

```
a();
wait(100ms);
b();
wait(100ms);
c();
```

At the moment i have a wait function, but instead i would like to have a promise or something, so i trigger b when a is done. All the three functions have asynchronus ajax calls in them, but return true before the ajax calls is done.
I would like to rewrite the code, but thats no option atm. due to a lot of this code is used everywhere...

Comment: Rewrite, it will be better in the long run as your current solution is not viable.

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: Yeah, I know but i am editing in a existing plugin thats made by god now who.. And  i need to fix this asap...

Comment: My question is there some solution to wait for a before i trigger b.

Comment: Yes, you mentioned it it promise/callback.

Comment: You said that those functions return true even before the ajax call was done, if so there is no way of telling if the ajax is really done or not. In other words to make it happen, you need a real async functions in there and then you might convert them to promises.

Comment: But will the promise wait for the asynchronus ajax call in a for example?

Comment: Please read up on promises.

Answer (score 1):

I guess passing a callback to the function and call it after the execution will make a difference. For example...

```
function a(cb) {
    ajaxfunction(
        .. stuff to do
        cb(param)
    );
}

a(function(param){

})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you *always* want to run these three functions, regardless of their return value, you could as well use `setTimeout()` to run them without using `wait()`.